# Converting JSONArray to HashMap and Matching

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap

I have a JSONArray that has data in following format :

```
[[{ "Country" : "IN", "count" : 10},{ "Country" : "US", "count" : 20}],
[{ "Country" : "IN", "count" : 10},{ "Country" : "US", "count" : 20}]]
```

I want to put the data to an HashMap, something like this :

```
"IN":10
"US":20
"IN":10
"US":20
```

Basically, I am doing a count match so as to ensure all `Country` of a type have same `count`.

Here is what I tried, JSONArray is stored as `myArray` :

```
Map<String, Integer> cargo = new HashMap<>();
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length(); j++) {
  String country = myArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("country");
  Integer count = myArray.getJSONObject(j).getInt("count");
  cargo.put(country, count);
}
```

But I get `JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject` error.

Thanks,

Edit : This helped me get it to map.

`

```
Map<String, Integer> cargo = new HashMap<>();
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length(); j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < myArray.getJSONArray(j).length(); k++) {
    String country = myArray.getJSONArray(j).getJSONObject(k).getString("country");
    Integer count = myArray.getJSONArray(j).getJSONObject(k).getInt("count");
    cargo.put(country, count);
  }
```

`

Comment: Your json is an array of arrays so you need an extra loop over each array.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JSONArray[0]` equals to

`[{ "Country" : "IN", "count" : 10},{ "Country" : "US", "count" : 20}]`

So not an `JSONObject` indeed, you need to do a `for` inside a `for`, to iterate every object.

---

```
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length(); j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < myArray[j].length(); k++) {
    String country = myArray[j].getJSONObject(k).getString("country");
    Integer count = myArray[j].getJSONObject(k).getInt("count");
    cargo.put(country, count);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried this, But for the second loop, I get `the type of the expression should be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray`.

Comment: So find a way to loop an JSONArray :)

Comment: Ya. I found. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is an array of arrays so you need an extra loop over each array.